# Update table column Where

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have `productinfo` table and `product_temp` table. 
I want to update the field `UpdateDate` of table `productinfo` where `productinfo.ProductID = productinfo_temp.ProductID`

But the below code is not working.

```
UPDATE productinfo a 
SET UpdateDate = productinfo_temp.UpdateDate 
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM productinfo_temp b WHERE a.ProductID = b.ProductID)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE productinfo a JOIN productinfo_temp b ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
SET a.UpdateDate = b.UpdateDate
```

Answer (score 3):

use `UPDATE with JOIN`

```
UPDATE  productinfo a  
        INNER JOIN productinfo_temp b
            ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
SET     a.UpdateDate = b.UpdateDate
```